# Image Classification: train_datagen.flow_from_directory not picking up any images

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, keras

I split the images into train val and test folders for a keras image classification CNN. However, train_datagen.flow_from_directory not picking up any images. It says: Found 0 images belonging to 21 classes. I checked the directories and they seem fine.
'''

```
import splitfolders
splitfolders.ratio('imagetype', output="output", seed=1337, ratio=(.8, 0.1,0.1)) 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_path = "/home/ubuntu/imageTrain_dobby/SKJEWELLERY/BC4U/google_version/v1.1/lingyau_lee/output/train/"
val_path = "/home/ubuntu/imageTrain_dobby/SKJEWELLERY/BC4U/google_version/v1.1/lingyau_lee/output/val/"
test_path = "/home/ubuntu/imageTrain_dobby/SKJEWELLERY/BC4U/google_version/v1.1/lingyau_lee/output/test/"

img_width, img_height = 225,225 #1000, 1143
batch_size = 10

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)
 
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)
 
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical")
 
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical")
```

'''

Comment: The path needs to be to a folder, that contains folders, that contains the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should lead to folders with classes, for each class, there should be 1 folder.